# StreamSets preview data from MySQL error

Tags: jdbc, streamsets

I was attempting to use StreamSets to query a MySQL database and publish the data into Elasticsearch (localhost).

I downloaded StreamSets' tarball on my Mac and unzipped it into my home directory. Running StreamSets dc started up on my first try, then I followed the instructions here to add the jdbc driver, then the instructions here to configure my StreamSets job. However, I got an error:

> JDBC_00 - Cannot connect to specified database:
>   com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_06 - Failed to
>   initialize connection pool:
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during
>   pool initialization: Connection.isValid() is not supported, configure
>   connection test query.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using an old MySQL JDBC driver (pre-JDBC 4.0)?

Based on the error you need to go to the Legacy configuration tab and specify a test query yourself such as SELECT USER() or SELECT 1 from 1 so that connections can be validated.